# Typings install specific version of definition files

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I am new to TypeScript. I want to install a specific version of angular definition file to my application.

Using `TSD` i can use the following command

```
tsd install angular -v "1.4.0" -rso
```

Since, `TSD` is deprecated, i have shifted to `typings` to automate the definition files installation.

My question is, using `typings`, can i install a particular version of angular definition file? If so then what's the command in `typings`?

**Update:**

I tried below commands but they didn't work.

```
typings install angular@1.4.0
```

and

```
typings install angular@1.4.0 --ambient
```

The error messages look like:

```
$ typings install angular@1.4.0 --ambient
typings ERR! message Unable to find "angular" for "dt" in the registry. Did you want to install ambient typings with the ambient flag? If you can contribute these typings, please help us: https://github.com/typings/registry
typings ERR! caused by https://api.typings.org/entries/dt/angular/versions/1.4.0/latest responded with 404, expected it to equal 200

typings ERR! cwd /Users/idolezalova/projects/wfm
typings ERR! system Darwin 15.4.0
typings ERR! command "/Users/idolezalova/.nvm/versions/node/v4.3.1/bin/node" "/Users/idolezalova/.nvm/versions/node/v4.3.1/bin/typings" "install" "angular@1.4.0" "--ambient"
typings ERR! node -v v4.3.1
typings ERR! typings -v 0.7.12

typings ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
typings ERR!   <https://github.com/typings/typings/issues>
```

Comment: Reported as a bug https://github.com/typings/typings/issues/442

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From help:

```
$ typings install -h

typings install (with no arguments, in package directory)
typings install <pkg>[@<version>] [ --source [dt | npm | github | bower | common | shared | lib | env | global] ]
typings install file:<path>
typings install github:<github username>/<github project>[/<path>][#<commit>]
typings install bitbucket:<bitbucket username>/<bitbucket project>[/<path>][#<commit>]
typings install <http:// url>

Aliases: i, in
Options: [--name] [--save|--save-dev] [--ambient] [--production]
```

That means this command should work (you also need to add `--ambient` flag because it is not ported from `DefinitelyTyped` yet):

```
typings install angular@1.4.0 --ambient
```

Comment: @imfarhad Hmm, I see. Well, it seems like a bug, I would report it as issue on GitHub.

Comment: I would say that the problem is with DT repository for [angular typings](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/angularjs). Version 1.4 is inside folder named *legacy*, typings probably does not know to handle it.